# TextBook contradicting its own statement

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

I have to find the values of $k$ for which the equation:$$x^4-(k-3)x^2+k=0$$ has : (i) four real roots and (ii) exactly 2 real roots.

**My solution:** put $x^2=t$, then the equation becomes $$t^2-(k-3)t+k=0       ......(1)$$ For (i) we need (1) to have 2 positive roots-real or distinct.
For (ii) we need (1) to have one positive and one negative root.

**But what my book does:** For (i) it only considers the case when (1) has positive and distinct roots, and hence doesn't consider k=9 in the solution set. But I think that $(x^2-3)^2=0$ *has* 4 real roots.

For (ii), in addition to my consideration, it also takes into account the case where (1) has real equal positive roots. But that would make the original equation to have 4 real roots.

Also the book mentioned a few pages ago that:

> Difference between root and solution: A root of a polynomial equation may be real or imaginery while a solution has to be real. A quadratic equation having two distinct real roots is said to have two solutions. If it has two equal real roots then it has one solution. If it has two imaginery roots then we say that the equation has no solution.

Is the book contradicting its own(extrapolated) statement or am I wrong?

---

My solution for (i):

for (1) to have two positive roots(equal or distinct) we need:

Sum of roots$\gt0$ that is $k-3>0\Rightarrow k>3$,

Product of roots$\gt0$ that is $k>0$ and

$$D\geq0$$

$$(k-1)(k-9)\geq0$$
$$k\in(-\infty,1]\cup[9,\infty)$$

Taking intersection of all these intervals we get$$[9,\infty)$$.

Comment: For (ii) you may also want to have just one real positive root, like in $(t-1)^2 = 0,$ which results in $x=-1$ or $x=1.$

Comment: My guess is that they wanted to say distinct real roots

Answer (score 2):

> But I think that $(x^2−3)^2=0$ has 4 real roots.

This has 4 real roots but *those roots are pairwise equal*. This means that the roots are $\sqrt{3},\sqrt{3},-\sqrt{3},-\sqrt{3}$. Your book probably means 4 **distinct** real roots, which this equation doesn't have.

For (ii), as you said, if (1) has a real equal positive root $u$, then $x^2 = u \implies x = \pm \sqrt{u}$. This also has pairwise equal roots $ \sqrt{u}, \sqrt{u}, - \sqrt{u}, - \sqrt{u}$. This means that it would have 4 roots in this case.

Your book probably missed out the word **distinct** in both parts of the question. Adding that word would make the textbook answer the correct one.

Comment: Acc. to your suggestion, (ii) becomes "exactly 2-but distinct-real roots"(other 2 imaginery). But still the book's consideration of "real equal positive root" doesn't fit here, as in that case we have 2 distinct real *solutions*, not *roots* (acc to the quote), instead we have 4 pairwise equal real roots(as u mentioned). This makes the book's answer wrong(in (ii) only, (i) is fine though), contrary to your last statement.  I think this case doesn't fit here at all, as exactly 2 real roots WILL make those 2 real roots distinct only, there is no other way for them to exist.